# import bootstrap-sass to scss file

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass

How to import bootstrap-sass to scss file? without compass, without rails, without etc. 
I just only have 2 files, .html and .scss (which later will be generated to css). 
I know there's a lot questions how to import bootstrap-sass but everything use rails or compass

I already gem install bootstrap-sass,  but I don't know what shall I do afterthat

Comment: To run Sass from the command line, just use `sass input.scss output.css` and/or see http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#using_sass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.scss` file

```
// Import Bootstrap Compass integration
@import "bootstrap-compass"

// Import custom Bootstrap variables
@import "bootstrap-variables"

// Import Bootstrap for Sass
@import "bootstrap"
```

make sure you give proper path to your `.scss` libraries of `bootstrap`. and the `ordering` of the inclusion is important.

Comment: Oh I see, later sass will compile it, lack of knowledge, tee hee :D Thank you